# The requested URL was not found on this server. Django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I try to write the comment on page and then instead redirect on page I have the empty window in browser and 
`[b'<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /post/add_comment/test_single_post/ was not found on this server.</p>']` and `AssertionError: 404 != 302`
 in terminal log.
I can't understand why page is not found (404) in this case.

view

```
class SinglePost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        comment_form = CommentForm
        context = super(SinglePost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        comments = Comments.objects.filter(comment_id=self.object).order_by('-added')
        context['comments'] = comments
        context['form'] = comment_form
        return context


@csrf_protect
def add_comment(request, slug):
    """
    Add comment to.
    """
    if request.POST:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.comment = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
            form.save()
    return redirect('/post/{0}/'.format(slug))
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>\S+)/$', SinglePost.as_view(),
                                    name='single_post'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>\S+)/$', TagView.as_view(),
                                    name='tagger'),
    url(r'^post/add_comment/(?P<slug>\S+)/$',
        'blog.views.add_comment', name="commenter"),
    url(r'^$', PostsList.as_view(), name="all_posts"),
)
```

template

```
<h3>Comments:</h3>
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p>{{ comment.added }} | {{ comment.author }}</p>
    <p>{{ comment.comment_text }}</p>
{% empty %}
    <p>There are no comments here yet. Be first :)</p>
{% endfor %}
<form action="/post/add_comment/{{ object.slug }}/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.subject.errors }}
        <label for="id_author">Add your name:</label><br>
        {{ form.author|addclass:"form-control" }}
        <br/>
        <label for="id_comment_text">Add your comment here:</label><br>
        {{ form.comment_text|addclass:'form-control comment-textarea' }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add comment" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Can anyone give me an answer how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `single_post` regex catches all urls started with 'post/'.  Place this url at the end of the patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>\S+)/$', TagView.as_view(),
                                    name='tagger'),
    url(r'^post/add_comment/(?P<slug>\S+)/$',
        'blog.views.add_comment', name="commenter"),
    url(r'^$', PostsList.as_view(), name="all_posts"),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>\S+)/$', SinglePost.as_view(),
                                    name='single_post'),
)
```

Or, as a more correct solution, change the `\S+` regex to valid slug regex `[\w-]+`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SinglePost.as_view(),
                                    name='single_post'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', TagView.as_view(),
                                    name='tagger'),
    url(r'^post/add_comment/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        'blog.views.add_comment', name="commenter"),
    url(r'^$', PostsList.as_view(), name="all_posts"),
)
```

Comment: Thank you again, catavaran. It's my absence of mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have two regular expressions which are overlapping:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>\S+)/$', SinglePost.as_view(),
                                name='single_post'),
[...]
url(r'^post/add_comment/(?P<slug>\S+)/$',
```

You should change the first one to be less greedy, for example: `r'^post/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$'` or place it at the end.